# PHP: Year does not change when subtracting 1 year in while loop

Tags: php, while-loop, strtotime

I want to display all the years in descending order starting from the current year to 2014. However, when I try to loop and subtract the variable containing the year value, it doesn't change. It stays to 2020. What am I missing? Here's my code:

```
$curyear = date("Y");
while ($curyear > "2014"){
      $subyear = date('Y', strtotime($curyear. ' - 1 year'));
      $curyear = $subyear;
      echo $curyear;
}
```

Comment: I think it is because you use 'strtotime'.  strtotime expects a valid string date while using a year only is invalid.

Comment: @CharlesEF ahhh I see. That explains why. I suppose I need to read more about the strtotime docs. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to subtract the 'year' type u can just directly subtract subtract 1 like so

```
$curyear = date("Y");
while ($curyear > "2014"){
     $curyear = $curyear -1;
     echo $curyear;
}
```

Comment: This is the quickest and correct way of doing this. However, I want to understand what's wrong with my code. It's technically doing the same as yours though with date() and strtotime()

Comment: not sure i tried `strtotime("-1 year")` alone and still got 2020, it could be a syntax issue hope u find out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The datetime format you passed to [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function is ambiguous, for example:

```php
# Current datetime: 2021-06-29 14:41:05
# Only the third print meets your expectations
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2021 - 1 year')), PHP_EOL; # 2020-06-29 20:21:00, 2021 -> 20:21:00
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2001 - 1 year')), PHP_EOL; # 2020-06-29 20:01:00, 2001 -> 20:01:00
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('1999 - 1 year')), PHP_EOL; # 1998-06-29 14:41:05, 1999 - 1 -> 1998
```

And it is easy to fix, combine year with month and date to prevent ambiguity:

```php
$curyear = date("Y");
while ($curyear > "2014"){
      # $subyear = date('Y', strtotime($curyear. ' - 1 year'));
      $subyear = date('Y', strtotime("$curyear-01-01 - 1 year"));
      $curyear = $subyear;
      echo $curyear;
}
```